# How to Deal with a Job Offer If Currently Working

Tags: salary, job-offer

How can someone handle an unofficial job offer from Company A while already employed at Company B, especially when they haven't been informed about the salary and benefits offered by Company A?

Should he "accept" that job offer and try to negotiate the salary based on what his current salary is? Basically should even entertain the possibility of accepting the unofficial offer just to see how it compares to his current job?

Comment: What's a "unofficial job offer"? Job offers in general are just that, a proposition, nothing else, and until you have a contract in hand that's signed - you have nothing.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul: Basically I would get the job if I asked for it,  but I don't know the salary yet. That is what it is. Then I would get a formal offer with salary, benefits, etc.

Comment: You do NOT have a job offer, you are simply in the early phases of the hiring process. DO NOT make a decision or quit your current gig until you have a signed, fully negotiated and mutually agreed offer or contract in hand.

Comment: You respond to company A with "I would consider an offer if the terms are desirable".

Answer (score 11):

> Basically I would get the job if I asked for it, but I don't know the salary yet. That is what it is. Then I would get a formal offer with salary, benefits, etc.

Job offer with no terms, salary, starting date is not a job offer; it's nothing, and that's all you have now. It's important to get that clear and out of the way that we are at the same level - unless it's a job offer, in writing, with all the details and already signed by the other party you got absolutely nothing.

Thus...

> Should he "accept" that job offer and try to negotiate the salary based on what his current salary is?

There is no job offer to accept... Yet. So lets get to the crux of what the question is all about:

> How to handle a situation where I, maybe, can get a better job somewhere else, but I am currently employed and want to be very careful, as nothing is set in stone yet.

I wouldn't handle this as any other interview/job ad. Reach out, ask all the questions you want to know, like salary, and when you have all the information and it seems worth the effort ask to apply and go through whatever process there is.

If the process truly is as simple as "I just have to ask", great! You are not far off. But if that's the case, no one should be surprised by a question of nature "hey, if I were to join you as ACME maintenance officer, what would my pay be?".

And if that matches your interest, proceed with the application (as informal as it may be) and hopefully at the end of it there's an actual job.

Comment: So should I tell the person that I am interested in moving forward? He doesn't know the salary etc. only his manager does. He would just tell his manager about my interest. Would I then ask that manager about the salary specifics etc?

Comment: @user21478 I guess htat's the process so yeah, just think about it as normal job application and carry on.

Answer (score 5):

> How can someone handle an unofficial job offer from Company A while already employed at Company B, especially when they haven't been informed about the salary and benefits offered by Company A?

An unofficial job offer requires more discussion, if the job seems appealing. Otherwise, there's nothing to handle, unless and until it becomes official.

If you like the company, job, and unofficial offer, ask whatever you need to ask (salary, benefits, responsibility, etc.) and negotiate whatever you need to negotiate to help it become official, then make a decision.

Comment: So  I tell the person that I am interested in moving forward? He doesn't know the salary etc. only his manager does. He would just tell his manager about my interest. Would I then ask that manager about the salary specifics etc?

Comment: Yes, assuming you have enough interest in the offered position that it would lure you away from your current job

Answer (score 2):

Job application usually follow these stages:

1. Know about a job offer, for example: from job ads, recruiter, friend or relative
2. Gather necessary information, for example: salary, position, job description, location
3. Apply for the job
4. Be employed officially

You are at number 1. You can jump to 3 and apply for the job without knowing the salary, but ask yourself: will it worth my time if it turns out it pays less than your current job?

Of course there are a lot of other factors, so try to find out as much as you can before you decide to apply and follow through the application process (skill tests, interviews, official offering letter, etc.) so you don't waste your time and energy.

My advice would be approaching the source of the job offer and informally ask questions, and then the official contact where you can gather more information and verify. Then, based on information you gathered, decide whether to follow through and apply.

Answer (score 0):

Until you have written offer, you don't need to concern yourself or do anything

There is no decision to be made :)